# ¿Cómo formatear horas con daterangepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, daterangepicker

Estoy realizando un formulario que involucra fechas y horas. El detalle es que estoy usando `daterangepicker` y quisiera saber cómo poner en el `input` el formato hora con `daterangepicker`. No quiero usar otra librería porque ya estoy usando una y agregar otra por solo un campo no lo veo óptimo.

Mi formulario se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El HTML de la fecha y hora:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3 input-group-sm">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">FECHA</span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " name="fecha_inicio" id="fecha_inicio" >

              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">HORA</span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " name="hora_inicio" id="hora_inicio">
            </div>
```

El código JavaScript de la fecha actual con `daterangepicker`:

```
    $('#fecha_inicio').daterangepicker({
        singleDatePicker: true,
         minDate: '<?php echo date("d/m/Y");?>',
         locale: {
         format: 'DD/MM/YYYY' }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     $('#hora_inicio').daterangepicker({
        timePicker : true,
        singleDatePicker:true,
        timePicker24Hour : true,
        timePickerIncrement : 1,
        timePickerSeconds : true,
        locale : {
            format : 'HH:mm:ss'
        }
    }).on('show.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        picker.container.find(".calendar-table").hide();
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

La librería no tiene la posibilidad de mostrar solo horas, lo que podrías hacer es limitar la fecha para que no pueda cambiarla añadiendo `startDate` y `endDate`. De esta manera no podrá cambiar la hora solo elegir horas.

No es una solución perfecta pero es lo que puedes hacer con esta librería.

### Opción A

```
$('#hora_inicio').daterangepicker({
        "singleDatePicker": true,
        "timePicker": true,
        "timePicker24Hour": true,
        "timePickerSeconds": true,
        "linkedCalendars": false,
        "startDate": '<?php echo date("d/m/Y");?>',
        "endDate": '<?php echo date("d/m/Y");?>',
    }, function(start, end, label) {
      console.log('New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')');
    });
```

### Opción B

Permitir que tu input fecha pueda añadir horas y minutos con `daterangepicker`, para ello solo tienes que habilitar la propiedad `timePicker` a `true`.

### Opción C

Usar el input de tipo time.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

```html
<input type="time" id="appt" name="appt"
       min="09:00" max="18:00" required>
```